# Show modal window and pass values arguments in (bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have button

```
<input type="button" value="Show URL" onclick="showUrlQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')" data-toggle="modal">
```

on click I need to show modal window and call method from controller
I added this code in `@section dialogs`

```
@section dialogs{

<div id="show_url_dialog" class="modal hide fade">
    @Html.Partial("_ShowUrlDialog")
</div>
```

}

and added this code in `script section`

```
function showUrlQuestionnaire(id) {
        $('#show_url_dialog').modal('show').val(id);
    };
```

created partial view

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    test text
</div>
```

but I don't know how to pass to model view and to partial view `id` and call in this partial view the method from controller?
this is method

```
[HttpGet]
    public string ShowUrlQuestionnaire(int id)
    {
        var questionnaire = QuestionnaireRepository.GetById(id);
        var questionnaireUrl = QuestionnaireService.GetQuestionnaireByGuid(Guid.Parse(questionnaire.QuestionnaireId.ToString()));
        return questionnaireUrl.ToString();
    }
```

I need to show in modal window returned string from this method.
Can someone explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach from what you're doing but it will help you solve your problem.
You could assign a url to the `href` property of an `anchor` tag which bootstrap will load and inject the result to the `body` of your `modal`

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/Home/ShowUrlQuestionnaire/@options.rowId" data-target="#show_url_dialog">click me</a>

<div id="show_url_dialog" class="modal hide fade">

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ShowUrlQuestionnaire(int id)
        {
            var questionnaire = QuestionnaireRepository.GetById(id);
            var questionnaireUrl = QuestionnaireService.GetQuestionnaireByGuid(Guid.Parse(questionnaire.QuestionnaireId.ToString()));
            ViewBag.QuestionnaireUrl = questionnaireUrl;
            return PartialView("_ShowUrlDialog");

        }
```

**ParitalView**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @ViewBag.QuestionnaireUrl
</div>
```

Comment: nope, your code doesn't work, I get empty modal window without any text

Comment: Hmm. Did it reach the controller?

Comment: It looks like no. I set `break` in `return PartialView("_ShowUrlDialog");` but got nothing.

Comment: Did you have the right url for your controller and action method in the `href` attribute?

Comment: Yes, because link `http://localhost:17000/Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire/2` is right ans it wokrs

Comment: So you have `<a data-toggle="modal" href="/Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire/2" data-target="#show_url_dialog">` ?

Comment: Try removing the `hide` class in your modal